# Cloudflare SSL 3rd Party Access Error

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, cloudflare, sslhandshakeexception

I try to submit my RSS feed:

https://www.ahcafr.com/feed/

To [feedvalidator.org](http://www.feedvalidator.org/) and I get error:

Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

It happens with all my Cloudflare sites. Why is that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I am getting an SSL error with my website, and it is related to software development, since this is how software errors arise. So what are you talking about? Where else should I post this?

Comment: *"[SSL errors] happens with all my Cloudflare sites. Why is that?"* is not a question that is on-topic here. Stack Overflow is for programming or development questions. Maybe you edit your question and swing it on-topic. Start by adding your code and providing your server configuration. The other comment suggests some Stack Exchange sites that may be able to help with the configuration of your website.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to use feedvalidator.org against my own site and doing a packet capture shows that feedvalidator.org uses a modern TLS version (TLS 1.2) but fails to use the `server_name` TLS extension ([SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) to indicate which specific host it wants to access. This extension is set by all modern web browsers and many sites rely on the client using this extension, as does your site behind Cloudflare.

A failure to use this extension by a client results in the handshake failure got. To fix the problem you either need to make your site accessible without SNI (some more expensive Cloudflare plans might offer this) or just ignore this feedvalidator and try to find one which uses more up-to-date behavior regarding HTTPS.